# One to Many mapping with an intermediate table

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I thought I had this one pegged by mapping the intermediary table as a HasMany and between intermediary and child as HasOne, however HasOne expects to share a key. (No Inverse option.:[ )

Anyhow, the relational structure I have:

> Address (Child)
>   AddressId
>   ..Address Fields
>   
>   AddressCustomer (Intermediary)
>   AddressCustomerId
>   AddressId
>   CustomerId
>   
>   Customer (Parent)
>   CustomerId
>   ..Customer Fields

Why I have this intermediary table instead of a normal 1-many? Because there will be other entities that will need to contain addresses. (I.e. Sites, etc.) They will have their own intermediary table so they can share the address table.

Mappings I have so far:

```
    public class CustomerAddressMap : ClassMap<CustomerAddress>
{
    public CustomerAddressMap()
    {
        Schema("dbo");
        Table("CustomerAddress");
        Id(x => x.CustomerAddressId);
        Map(x => x.FromDate)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.ToDate);
        HasOne(x => x.Address)
            .ForeignKey("AddressId")
            .Cascade.All();
    }

}

public class AddressMap : ClassMap<Address>
{
    public AddressMap()
    {
        Schema("dbo");
        Table("Address");
        Id(x=>x.AddressId);
        Map(x => x.AddressType);
    }
}
```

With a null-able AddressId column in the CustomerAddress table, rows are inserted, however the AddressID from the Address row doesn't propagate back up to CustomerAddress. There is no Inverse option on HasOne so that seems to be a dead end. I cannot have the Address ID generated on CustomerAddress because this would result in duplicates once I add something like SiteAddress and have to do the same thing. That trick *may* work with GUIDs as keys, but I'm stuck with auto-increment Ints for the moment.

Some other ideas I was noodling over was mapping a merge of CustomerAddress and Address but I don't believe that is supported with Fluent NHibby.

I figure it's a problem domain that someone has successfully applied. Essentially I want a 1-Many relationship where the child table (not it's records) is shared between multiple parents. Any ideas?

Comment: Update: After trying a few things still no perfect solution. I did try  switching the AddressID over to a GUID and setting it up as a .Reference() instead of a .HasOne() where the CustomerAddress and Site Address (added to verify it was working) were responsible for generating the Address ID. It works, however I'm not sure I can get buy-in to allow for GUID PK/FK for address details. 

If there is a possible solution around References or something similar that would allow Address to generate it's own key and have that updated in CustomerAddress/SiteAddress I will be elated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

map it as normal references

```
public class CustomerAddressMap : ClassMap<CustomerAddress>
{
    public CustomerAddressMap()
    {
        Table("CustomerAddress");

        Id(x => x.CustomerAddressId);
        Map(x => x.FromDate).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.ToDate);
        References(x => x.Customer, "CustomerId");
        References(x => x.Address, "AddressId");
    }
}
```

Comment: Aw man, the tinkering to get it to work with GUID the way I thought it should actually works with the int ID, all I had to do was switch back the type, didn't think it would have worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you make one-to-many from address to customer? Customer will contain foreign key then and address entity could be referened by other entity. In this case, you simply make `References(x => x.Address);` on customer table.
When I was trying to create one-to-one relation using FluentNHibernate, I faced common problems too. If you want to leave DB structure as you showed, I guess you should try the following mapping (with adding corresponding entity fields):

```
 public AddressMap()
 {
    Schema("dbo");
    Table("Address");
    Id(x => x.AddressId);
    Map(x => x.AddressType);
    HasOne(x => x.CustomerAddress).Cascade.All();
 }
 public CustomerAddressMap()
 {
     Schema("dbo");
     Table("CustomerAddress");
     Id(x => x.CustomerAddressId);
     Map(x => x.FromDate)
         .Not.Nullable();
     Map(x => x.ToDate);
     HasOne(x => x.Address)
     .Constrained()
     .ForeignKey();
 }
```

Such mapping left in my case one side empty, so I modified property setter for child entity (CustomerAddress):

```
public virtual Address Address
{ 
    get { return _address; }
    set 
    {
        _address = value;
        value.CustomerAddress = this;
    }
}
```

After these actions one-to-one worked fine) Hope it will help you to solve the problem.