# Entity Framework map one to many with an intermediate table without a class for that table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-mapping

I have

```
Issue
{
    //Id, etc
    public List<CloudFile> Files { get; set; }
}
```

and since `CloudFile` can be used by other classes, the cleanest solution seems to create an intermediate table called `IssueFile`. The thing is I have no use for such a class in my code... so how do I map between `Issue` and `CloudFile` without creating such an intermediate class. Or is this even possible? I know that there are similar questions ([One to Many mapping with an intermediate table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12737194/550975)) but they create this intermediate but, hopefully, unnecessary class.

Comment: Why do you think you need a junction table for a 1:N relationship?  Your design seems like it may be flawed; perhaps you should post examples of these 'other classes' that can reference `CloudFile`s

Comment: For example a `User` can have `CloudFile`s, an  `Order` can have `CloudFile`s and I don't want to have the `CloudFile` table have 3 foreign keys, 2 of which will always be `null` I feel like the cleaner approach is to have an intermediate table for each of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is Table-per-Type (TPT) inheritance.  `CloudFile` would be your base class and the derived types would represent the relationship to the owning entities (`Issue`, `Order`, etc.):

```
[Table( "CloudFile" )]
public class CloudFile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Table( "IssueCloudFile" )]
public class IssueCloudFile : CloudFile
{
}

public class Issue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<IssueCloudFile> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Or via Fluent API:

```
modelBulider.Entity<CloudFile>().ToTable( "CloudFile" );
modelBuilder.Entity<IssueCloudFile>().ToTable( "IssueCloudFile" );
```

If you use `DbSet<CloudFile>` only without `DbSet`s for a derived type of `CloudFile`, use `.OfType<T>()` to get only those types:

```
var issueCloudFiles = db.CloudFiles.OfType<IssueCloudFile>();
// or through the referencing entities themselves
issueCloudFiles = db.Issues.SelectMany( i => i.Files );
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only time there is no getting out of an intermediate table is for a many-to-many mapping. In your case, you're dealing with a many-to-optional or many-to-required. Now you have two options:

1) Foreign Key association: for this you will need to define your foreign key in your `CloudFile` class. This has some advantages, because you can update relationships by changing foreign key value and you can add new entities without needing the dependant entity by using dummy foreign key values. Overall it's just easier to work with.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Issue>()
  .HasMany(i => i.CloudFile)
  .WithRequired(i => i.Issue)
  .HasForeignKey(i => i.Id);
```

2) Independant association: no foreign key on your model (it does use the key internally of course) and the relationship has it's own state tracked.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Issue>()
  .HasMany(i => i.CloudFile)
  .WithRequired(i => i.Issue)
  .Map(i => i.MapKey("Id"));
```

Comment: The problem is that the `CloudFile` table will get a `Issue_Id` or whatever foreign key. As I stated though, `CloudFile` will be used by other things other than `Issues`. This would mean my `CloudFile` table would end up with multiple foreign keys to all of these other tables. I don't want that. I want an intermediate table that maps `CloudFile` to `Issue`, called `IssueFile`. The point of my question is how do I map this set up in `EF` without needing to create an `IssueFile` class that I will never actually need in my code. I know I need the table, but how can I avoid needing the class.

Comment: Why would you prefer an extra table over an extra column for a foreign key? With independent association EF takes care of the foreign key in the background so you'll never have to deal with it, won't even be in your models. As soon as you have a junction table you're dealing with many-to-many, no way around it.

Comment: Because that makes my table ugly. It forces me to have many nulls in most of those columns... it's just a bad way to do things. I didn't realize that many-to-many was off the table... it's not.